# how to make UIView come out from one side of another UIView with animation?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using swift in my project. in this project I have one UIView(called mySubView1) inside UIViewController and another one (called mySubView2) inside mySubView1 (mySubView2 contain some data to show).
like this:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|                                         |
|                                         |
|             myViewController            |
|                                         |
|        ++++++++++++++++++++++++         | 
|        |      mySubView1      |         |
|        |                      |         |                                               
|        |  ++++++++++++++++++  |         |
|        |  |   mySubView2   |  |         |
|        |  ++++++++++++++++++  |         |
|        ++++++++++++++++++++++++         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

then mySubView2 come out of mySubView1 and passed the bottom of mySubView1 with animation like this:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|                                         |
|                                         |
|             myViewController            |
|                                         |
|        ++++++++++++++++++++++++         | 
|        |      mySubView1      |         |
|        |                      |         |                                               
|        |  ++++++++++++++++++  |         |
|        |  |   mySubView2   |  |         |
|        |  |                |  |         |
|        +++|                |++|         |
|           |    someData    |            |
|           |                |            |
|           ++++++++++++++++++            |
|                                         |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

imagine a printer that print some data on paper(myViewController as printer and mySubView1 as printer output and mySubView2 as paper)

**UPDATED:**
I'm using NSLayoutAnchor in my project:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let heightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint
    let mySubView1 = UIView()
    mySubView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mySubView1.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.addSubview(mySubView1)

    mySubView1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    mySubView1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    mySubView1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
    mySubView1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    let mySubView2 = UIView()
    mySubView2.clipsToBounds = true
    mySubView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mySubView2.backgroundColor = .yellow
    view.addSubview(mySubView2)

    mySubView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySubView1.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    mySubView2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySubView1.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    mySubView2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mySubView1.widthAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
    heightAnchor = mySubView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    heightAnchor.isActive = true
    heightAnchor.constant = 500
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {

        mySubView2.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of things that could be done. It would be helpful if you can show the constraints you have added or anything you have tried

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to follow these simple steps:

1. Firstly make sure `subView1` and `subView2` are added as subviews of `ViewController`'s `view`.
2. Make sure both views are constrained appropriately. And you have given a `heightAnchor` constraint to `subView2`.
3. Now increase the constant value of `heightAnchor` constraint of `subView2` and call `view.layoutSubViews()` inside the `UIView.animate`'s completion block.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is:

- Add both `mySubView1` & `mySubView2` as sub-views of the view controller.
- Send `mySubView1` to a lower index than `mySubView2`
- Use both of these calls to achieve the previous step:

  `self.view.sendSubview(toBack:mySubView1)`

  `self.view.bringSubview(toFront:mySubView2)`
- Animate the bounds of `mySubView2` to grow in the `Y` direction

Comment: I'm using NSLayoutAnchor in my project.